# Google Sheets query not working when referencing a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I use the query function to extract data from my tables in google sheets. But one of the conditions must be a reference to another cell. I do it like this:

```
=QUERY({$A2:$B,ArrayFormula(Month($C$2:$C)),$D2:D},"Select SUM(Col4) Where (Col3 = '"&H2&"' ) label sum(Col4) ''",0)
```

The above result is `#N/A`. (The field `H2` above contains the number `10`).

If I replace the `'"&H2&"'` with the actual number, like below, I get output:

```
=QUERY({$A2:$B,ArrayFormula(Month($C$2:$C)),$D2:D},"Select SUM(Col4) Where (Col3 = 10 ) label sum(Col4) ''",0)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes are unnecessary in case of numbers:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    $A2:$B,
    ARRAYFORMULA(Month($C$2:$C)),
    $D2:D
  },
  "SELECT SUM(Col4)
   WHERE Col3 = " & H2 & "
   LABEL SUM(Col4) ''",
)
```

Or you could use `MONTH` inside `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(
  {A:D},
  "SELECT SUM(Col4)
   WHERE MONTH(Col3) = " & H2 - 1 & "
   LABEL SUM(Col4) ''",
)
```

`MONTH` in `QUERY` is 0-based, so there is `H2 - 1`.